# Exact Meaning of Controlled Variables in terms of the OLS estimators

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

Consider a two-regressors linear regression model:
$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\beta_2D+u$$
where $X$ is continuous and $D$ is binary.

In this case, we say that we have controlled $D$.

Here, I want to know the exact meaning of "controlled".

Before I present my idea, consider three estimators.

First, let $\widehat{\beta}_1$ be the OLS estimator using the two-regressors model above.

Second, let $\widehat{\beta}_{11}$ and $\widehat{\beta}_{10}$ be the OLS estimator using only the sample with $D=1$ and $D=0$, respectively, based on
$$Y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1X+e$$

If $\widehat{\beta}_1$ is a weighted average of $\widehat{\beta}_{11}$ and $\widehat{\beta}_{10}$, the term "controlled" is quite valid because $\widehat{\beta}_{11}$ and $\widehat{\beta}_{10}$ are estimated while controlling $D$.

But, I am not sure, whether this idea is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regression, the terms used for defining $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p$ include independent variables, explanatory variables, predictors, regressors, covariates, or control variables. These terms are often interchangeable. The term "control" is more commonly applied in experimental sciences, where the experimenter has direct influence over $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_p$.

For example in econometric inference, the convention is to distinguish between two types of variables:

1. Variables in the population model, which are dictated by the underlying economic theory and are meant to explain the dependent variable.
2. Control variables, which are included in the regression to mitigate omitted variables bias.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, my point is whether the 2-regressors OLS estimator using the entire sample can be written as a weighted average of the other two subsample OLS estimators.

Comment: The term "control variables" is, perhaps more used in experimental designs and in econometrics. But the idea of controlling for other variables is used in all types of designs and all sorts of subjects.

Comment: @MinChulPark no, they are not a weighted average. You can easily check that with simulated toy data.

Comment: @Barbab Thank you. I have just checked that the pooled estimation is not an weighted average. But, I found that often the pooled estimation results lie between the separate simple regression coefficients. So, I guess that the pooled one could be a combination of the separate ones. Is there any theoretical results you know about this?